# cucumber reusing steps in web_steps.rb in my own step definitions myfeature_steps.rb

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I am writing a step definition for a scenario that involves checking/unchecking boxes.  In the step definition I am trying to use existing step in web_steps.rb.  However I am getting the error: Undefined step: "I check 'rating'".  Is there something I have to do to make my myfeature_steps.rb aware of web_steps.rb.  Thanks!

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |uncheck, rating_list|
  ratings = rating_list.split(%r{,\s*})
  if uncheck
    ratings.each do |r|
      step "I uncheck #{r}"
    end
  else
    ratings.each do |r|
      step "I check #{r}"
    end
  end
end
```

The following step definition exist in web_steps.rb

```
When /^(?:|I )check "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  check(field)
end

When /^(?:|I )uncheck "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  uncheck(field)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to simply be missing quotes.  Instead of

```
step "I uncheck #{r}"
```

You need

```
step "I uncheck \"#{r}\""
```

But that could depend on what values you're actually supplying from the feature, you don't mention this but the error message suggests they are arriving wrapped in single quotes, which won't satisfy the definition in `web_steps.rb`.

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  I left my step definition as it is, but now I am supplying elements wrapped in double quotes in my step